# Traer datos y settearlo a TextView

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenos días tengo un problema para traer unos datos y setearlos a un TextView. Tengo una clase llama da ProductDaoImpl.java donde tengo mi método que hacer la conexión, hago la consulta pero también hago una instancia de Producto.java donde tento mis gets and sets, lo que hago es que si encuentra la el producto con ese ideArticulo seteo y return 1, pero si no lo encuentra return 0. Ahora lo que quiero hacer es traer esos valores a mi clase DescProductoActivity.java y usarlos para setearlos a mi TextView.

> IProductoDAO.java

```
public interface IProductoDAO {
    public boolean registrar(Producto producto);
    public List<Producto> obtener();
    public boolean actualizar(Producto producto);
    public boolean eliminar(Producto producto);
    public int obtenerUno(int codigo);
}
```

> ProductoDaoImpl.java

```
public class ProductoDaoImpl implements IProductoDAO {
    @Override
    public boolean registrar(Producto producto) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Producto> obtener() {
        Conexion conn = new Conexion();
        Statement st= null;
        ResultSet rs=null;

        List<Producto> listaProducto = new ArrayList<Producto>();

        try {
            if (conn.conexionDB() == null) {
                Log.d("---------------------ACCESO", "Error de acceso");
            } else {
                String query = "select * from Articulos";
                st = conn.conexionDB().createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery(query);

                while (rs.next()) {
                    Producto producto = new Producto();

                    producto.setId_articulo(rs.getInt(1));
                    producto.setCodigo(rs.getString(2));
                    producto.setDescripcion(rs.getString(3));
                    producto.setPiezas_paquete(rs.getInt(4));
                    producto.setProveedor(rs.getString(5));
                    producto.setPrecio_mayoreo(rs.getFloat(6));
                    producto.setPrecio_menudeo(rs.getFloat(7));
                    producto.setPrecio_compra(rs.getFloat(8));
                    producto.setPorc_iva(rs.getInt(9));
                    producto.setStatus(rs.getString(10));
                    producto.setExistencia(rs.getInt(11));
                    producto.setUltimo_costo(rs.getFloat(12));
                    producto.setStock(rs.getInt(13));
                    producto.setBloqueo(rs.getString(14));

                    listaProducto.add(producto);
                }
                st.close();
                rs.close(); //                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error: Clase ClienteDaoImple, método obtener");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return listaProducto;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean actualizar(Producto producto) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean eliminar(Producto producto) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int obtenerUno(int ideArticulo) {
        Conexion conn = new Conexion();
        Statement st= null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        int count = 0;

        try {
            if (conn.conexionDB() == null) {
                Log.d("---------------------ACCESO", "Error de acceso");
            } else {
                String query = "SELECT * FROM Articulos WHERE ideArticulo = "+ideArticulo;
                st = conn.conexionDB().createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery(query);

                while (rs.next()) {
                    Producto producto = new Producto();

                    producto.setId_articulo(rs.getInt(1));
                    producto.setCodigo(rs.getString(2));
                    producto.setDescripcion(rs.getString(3));
                    producto.setPiezas_paquete(rs.getInt(4));
                    producto.setProveedor(rs.getString(5));
                    producto.setPrecio_mayoreo(rs.getFloat(6));
                    producto.setPrecio_menudeo(rs.getFloat(7));
                    producto.setPrecio_compra(rs.getFloat(8));
                    producto.setPorc_iva(rs.getInt(9));
                    producto.setStatus(rs.getString(10));
                    producto.setExistencia(rs.getInt(11));
                    producto.setUltimo_costo(rs.getFloat(12));
                    producto.setStock(rs.getInt(13));
                    producto.setBloqueo(rs.getString(14));

                    count++;
                }
                st.close();
                rs.close(); //                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error: Clase ClienteDaoImple, método obtener");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (count != 0){
            count = 1;
            System.out.println("Si se encontro un registro");
        }
        return count;
    } }
```

> Clase donde quiero traer la informaciòn del producto
>   DescProductoActivity.java

```
public class DescProductoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Creo los elementos
    public Button btnMas;
    public Button btnMenos;
    public EditText txtVCantidad;
    public TextView txtVCancelar, txtVCod;
    public int cantidad = 1;

    Producto producto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_desc_producto);

        // Inicializo los elementoS
        btnMas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMas);
        btnMenos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMenos);
        txtVCantidad = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtVCantidad);
        txtVCancelar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVCancelar);
        txtVCod = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVCod);

        int ideArticulo = getIntent().getIntExtra("ideArticulo",0);
        Producto producto = new Producto();

        if (ideArticulo != 0){
            IProductoDAO dao= new ProductoDaoImpl();
            int status = dao.obtenerUno(ideArticulo);
            if (status ==1){
                System.out.println("Si encontro articulo con id:"+ideArticulo);
                Log.d("Estes es el codigo--------------",""+producto.getCodigo());

            }
        }


        btnMas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cantidad = Integer.parseInt(txtVCantidad.getText().toString());
                if (cantidad < 500) {
                    cantidad++;
                    txtVCantidad.setText(String.valueOf(cantidad));
                } else {

                }
            }
        });

//        btnMenos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                cantidad = Integer.parseInt(txtVCantidad.getText().toString());
//                if (cantidad > 1) {
//                    cantidad--;
//                    txtVCantidad.setText(String.valueOf(cantidad));
//                } else {
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La cantidad debe ser mayor a 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
//            }
//        });
//
//        txtVCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                finish();
//            }
//        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método obtenerUno en realidad debería retornarte un objeto de tipo Producto ( y no un entero)
Primero en tu interfaz cambia:

```
public Producto obtenerUno(int codigo); //public int obtenerUno(int codigo);
```

En tu implementacion
    public Producto obtenerUno(int ideArticulo) {
       Conexion conn = new Conexion();
        Statement st= null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        int count = 0;

```
    try {
        if (conn.conexionDB() == null) {
            Log.d("---------------------ACCESO", "Error de acceso");
        } else {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Articulos WHERE ideArticulo = "+ideArticulo;
            st = conn.conexionDB().createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()) {
                Producto producto = new Producto();

                producto.setId_articulo(rs.getInt(1));
                producto.setCodigo(rs.getString(2));
                producto.setDescripcion(rs.getString(3));
                producto.setPiezas_paquete(rs.getInt(4));
                producto.setProveedor(rs.getString(5));
                producto.setPrecio_mayoreo(rs.getFloat(6));
                producto.setPrecio_menudeo(rs.getFloat(7));
                producto.setPrecio_compra(rs.getFloat(8));
                producto.setPorc_iva(rs.getInt(9));
                producto.setStatus(rs.getString(10));
                producto.setExistencia(rs.getInt(11));
                producto.setUltimo_costo(rs.getFloat(12));
                producto.setStock(rs.getInt(13));
                producto.setBloqueo(rs.getString(14));
           count++;
            }
            st.close();
            rs.close(); //                conn.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error: Clase ClienteDaoImple, método obtener");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (count != 0){
        count = 1;
        System.out.println("Si se encontro un registro");
    }
    return producto;
}       

  }
```

En la clase de tu actividad lo puede usar asi:

```
Producto producto = dao.obtenerUno(ideArticulo);
if(producto != null{
   String dato = producto.getStatus(); //por mencionar alguno
 }
```

Comment: Me sigue trayendo null

Comment: Ya regrese el valor tipo Producto y donde quiero mis valores agregue lo siguiente Producto producto = new Producto();

        if (ideArticulo != 0){
            IProductoDAO dao= new ProductoDaoImpl();
            producto = dao.obtenerUno(ideArticulo);
            if (producto != null){
                System.out.println("Si encontro articulo con id:"+ideArticulo);
                Log.d("Estes es el codigo--------------",""+producto.getStatus());

            }
        }

Comment: y el Log me pinta null

Comment: En que punto trae null? sera que no encuentra ningun registro?

Comment: En todos los datos me trae null

Comment: Esta bien mi query?

Comment: No hay ningun error en el logcat?

Comment: Ya quedo, le habia movido a mi consulta

Comment: Muchas gracias Igmer Rodriguez

Comment: Esta bien @Javierfr un gusto

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que añadir esta linea para printar el valor que te devuelva la función en el TextView.

```
    if (ideArticulo != 0){
        IProductoDAO dao= new ProductoDaoImpl();
        int status = dao.obtenerUno(ideArticulo);
        if (status ==1){
            System.out.println("Si encontro articulo con id:"+ideArticulo);
            Log.d("Estes es el codigo--------------",""+producto.getCodigo());
        }
    }
    txtVCod.setText(ideArticulo.toString());
```

Comment: Esto no funciona porque no cuando hago product.getCodigo marca null